# Issues on using BeautifulSoup to scrape a specific tag and its checkbox data

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

This is the page I tried to make a crawler(http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/mycar/popup/mycarChart_4.php?zone=C&cno=639137&tbl=cyber). The problem is to collect the data from the part like images below:

[image]

[image]

Those parts are made of 'tr' tags for each item. What I would like to do is to make it separate between upper part and lower part, and to collect the data of each list including the number of count if it is checked. And then, finally print out as the format like below:

```
<Upper Part>
1 후드 0 0
2 프론트 휀더(좌) 0 0
......
8 트렁크 리드 1 0
Total : 1 0

<Lower Part>
1 프론트 패널
2 크로스 멤버
....
22 리어 패널 1 0
23 트렁크 플로어 0 0 
Total : 1 0
```

My code is like below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import quote
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import time

popup_inspection = "http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/mycar/popup/mycarChart_4.php?zone=C&cno=639137&tbl=cyber"

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(500, 300)
driver.get(popup_inspection)

soup_inspection = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

count_in = 0 # 골격
count_out = 0 # 외관

for insp_table in insp_tables[4].find_all('tr'):
    labels = insp_table.find_all('td', class_="center")
    for label in labels[:15]:

        if label.find("input", type="checkbox", checked=True):
            count_out += 1
            print (label.text)
        else:
            print(label.text)
    print("외관 이상 수: ", count_out)

    for label in labels[16:]:
        if label.find("input", type="checkbox", checked=True):
            count_in += 1
            print (label.text)
        else:
            print(label.text)
    print("골격 이상 수: ", count_in)
```

Please help me to work this out.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks for replying. At this moment, the problem is that I can't get the result that I would like to have, not the error massage. As you can see in my code, I tried to make 'tr' tags separate, one is from start to 15th, another is from 16th to the end. Do you have any idea about the reason my code doesn't work on that part?